# Optional field in TypeScript based on if a field exists

Tags: typescript

I have this interface:

```
export interface AuthBtn {
    link: string,
    text: string,
    onClick: (p1?: object, p2?: object)=> void,
}
```

And either the `link` or `onClick` field will exist, and I want the `interface` to only include either `link` & `text` or `onClick` & `text`

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

You need a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions).

```
export type AuthBtn =
  | {
    link: string,
    text: string,
    _tag: "link_text",
  } 
  | {
    onClick: (p1?: object, p2?: object)=> void,
    text: string,
    _tag: "onclick_text",
  }
```

The discriminant is not strictly necessary, but really useful in lots of situations.

Answer (score 0):

You need a union, like

```
export type AuthBtn1 =
  | {
    text: string,
    onClick: (p1?: object, p2?: object) => void,
  } | {
    text: string,
    link: string,
  }

declare let a1: AuthBtn1;
if ('link' in a1) {
  a1
  // ^?
  // let a1: {
  //   text: string;
  //   link: string;
  // }
}
```

If you don't like using `in` operatorm you need a distinct union

```
export type AuthBtn2 =
  | {
    text: string,
    onClick: (p1?: object, p2?: object) => void,
    link?: never,
  } | {
    text: string,
    link: string,
    onClick?: never,
  }

declare let a2: AuthBtn2;
if (a2.link) {
  a2
  // ^?
  // let a2: {
  //   text: string;
  //   link: string;
  //   onClick?: undefined;
  // }
}
```

(`|` in the beginning is noop, just for aligning)